# Computing Statistics of a form

Tags: coldfusion, statistics

I have a form with a Likert Scale. I need to compute the Mean (easy), the mode, the standard deviation and the median.

How can I do this? I have 10 groups of 11 radio boxes to make up the choices.

Comment: How on earth do you interprete the mean of a Likert Scale? What's the mean between good, very good and no opinion?

Comment: Not necessarily the mean but we can do some statistical analysis, plus I have 11 fields. Such as: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale#Scoring_and_analysis

I may also store results in a database then call on these scripts to give me the overall review of an employee.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CFLib](http://cflib.org) is your friend.

- [Mean](http://cflib.org/udf/Mean) - Returns the mean (average) value for a set of numeric values. These values can be passed as a list or one dimensional array.
- [Mode](http://cflib.org/udf/Mode) - Returns a structure that contains 2 keys: Mode and Frequency. Mode is the value with the greatest frequency in the set.
- [StdDevPop](http://cflib.org/udf/StdDevPop) - Returns the standard deviation calculated using the divisor n method. This method is used when you have all the values for an entire population.
- [Median](http://cflib.org/udf/Median) - Returns the median (middle) value for a set of numeric values. The values can come from a list or a one dimensional array.